# DateTime->format("U") doesn't return a value with timezone info

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

In PHP 5.2, I'm using the following code to get a timestamp from a DateTime object.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles") );

echo $dateTime->format("U");
```

the problem is that **format("U")** simply returns server timestamp, which is UTC.

How do I make it to return a timestamp from Pacific Time Zone (Los Angeles) ?

Comment: Timestamps are supposed to be in UTC (by definition seconds since the epoch in GMT). Skewing them to a localized representation is counterproductive and should be reserved for converting them into date strings right prior presentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your concept for timestamp is not right, timestamp is **timezone independent**, it is defined as **the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), 1 January 1970**.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting timezone at top of PHP script.  I think timestamps are always UTC.  Use date() function to format it into what you need.

```
    // set timezone to pacific time
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```